# How to get RGB value from the returned value of the method com.sun.glass.ui.Robot.getPixelColor()?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, awtrobot

I am trying to get the pixel colour below the mouse cursor in JavaFX. Since AWT Robot is having issue with JavaFX in Mac OS, I am planning to use com.sun.glass.ui.Robot.getPixelColor(). This method com.sun.glass.ui.Robot.getPixelColor() is found to return an integer value. So how can I derive the RGB value of the colour?

Also could anyone let me know if the AWTRobot class issue is going to be resolved in JavaFX 8?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a way to do this without resorting to private APIs. If you [snapshot](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot%28javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,%20javafx.scene.image.WritableImage%29) the Node to an Image, you can retrieve a [PixelReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#getPixelReader%28%29) and use it to [get the pixel color](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelReader.html#getColor%28int,%20int%29) at the given coordinates.

Comment: What I am trying to implement is not only for JavaFX node. It should work on whole desktop screen. Where ever the mouse cursor is placed, it should be able to pick the pixel colour below the cursor. Actually a similar application is already present in Mac OS (DigitalColor Meter). I am trying to implement the same with JavaFX.